# SpaceChem has uninstallable dependency

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

Back when SpaceChem was new, I purchased it direct from Zachtronics Industries (not via Steam or GOG).  Now I would like to install it on my amd64 Ubuntu 14.04.1 system.  So I downloaded their Linux release 1012 and did:

```
$ tar xzf ~/Downloads/SpaceChem-1012.tar.gz
$ ./make-amd64-package
$ sudo dpkg -i SpaceChem-amd64.deb
```

But this led to dependency problems I couldn't work out.

```
 zachtronicsindustries-spacechem : Depends: libmono-wcf3.0-cil (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
```

I do have various mono packages installed, including libmono-wcf3.0a-cil.  I can try running `zachtronicsindustries-spacechem` even though it was never configured.  The game music plays, but the screen is all black.

How can I correctly install SpaceChem or work around these issues?

Answer (score 2):

dpkg --force-depends --configure --pending
or being six hours ago, dpkg --purge SpaceChem-amd64, dpkg -i --force-depends SpaceChem-amd64.deb

Comment: Thanks. Now can I do something so apt-get doesn't always want to uninstall it?

Comment: But SpaceChem does work?  The Deb you made was for an older Ubuntu or for Debian - close to Ubuntu, but in this case, different enough.  There is a setting for Apt that turns off auto-fix of broken packages, but you really don't want to do that!  If you make the package into a different format (tgz?) to keep it away from the Apt/dpkg system you'd be fine.  "apt-mark manual libmono-wcf3.0a" will keep it from getting auto-removed if SpaceChem is the last program using it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what packages you have at your disposal, there may be a "better" way.

This is all on Kubuntu 16.04.

I have the Humble Bundle version of SpaceChem, which offers .deb and .rpm. The .deb had exactly the same problems as you're indicating.

So, I took the .rpm and converted it to a Debian package with:
`sudo alien --to-deb spacechem-1.0.12-2.fc17.x86_64.rpm`

Then installed it:
`sudo dpkg -i spacechem_1.0.12-3_amd64.deb`

Of course, this leaves out a bunch of dependencies... So install them!
`sudo apt install mono-runtime mono-reference-assemblies-2.0`

I haven't done any work with Mono on this install, so I believe that those two are the only required dependencies.

The executable ends up in /opt/spacechem/spacechem, which is not on my PATH, but it also installs a desktop launcher which works.